# I recently uninstalled python 3.10, and installed python 3.11 but my PowerShell does not detect it

Tags: python, windows, powershell

I used the command Python -V in my powershell (I use a Windows PC), but it gave me this error message: [Python Not Found](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EarMR.png). I have python installed on my computer[Python 3.11](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bKhaK.png), and I added it to Path. With my other IDEs, such as intellij, it detects python and works perfectly.

I suspect that there is an error with my python 3.11, but even after uninstalling python and re-installing it, my system still cannot find python.

All answers are appreciated, Thank You

Comment: You need to add python to `PATH` enviroment variable

Comment: It's impossible to diagnose your problem without additional information. The linked duplicate contains detailed troubleshooting steps. If they don't resolve your problem, please ask a _new_ question, building on what you've found while troubleshooting.